# Activation of venv from script not working

Tags: python, subprocess, python-venv

I am trying to create and activate a virtual environment from a Python script. However I keep getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source'
```

I have tried, following different suggestions from past questions on this page:

```
from subprocess import run
run(["python", "-m", "venv", "venvIA"])
run(["source", "venvIA/bin/activate"])
```

How can I correctly activate the virtual environment from my script? I also tried replacing `"source"` for `.` and other tricks I found online.

I am currently using Visual Studio code on a MacOS device but I am also planning on doing another similar code for Windows systems later, in case you know how to work with those too.